# Temporal Recursion in F# Interactive

Tags: recursion, f#-interactive, temporal

**Context:**
I've been using Extempore and Opusmodus to do computer assisted composition in live situations (programming classical music in front of audiences). Since I'm a professional .Net developer, I started writing my own software for .Net (combi of F# and C#) heavily influenced by both Extempore and Opusmodus. I now come to the point of implementing Temporal Recursion as it works in Extempore and can't find a way to do that on the .Net platform. Some directions and inspiration would be very helpful.

**Definition:**
A temporal recursion is most simply defined as any block of code (function, method, etc..) that schedules itself to be called back at some precise future point in time.

**Examples in Scheme:** In theory a standard recursive function is a temporally recursive function that calls itself back immediately - i.e. without any temporal delay. For example (in Scheme):

```
;; A standard recursive function

(define my-func
  (lambda (i)
    (println 'i: i)
    (if (< i 5) 
        (my-func (+ i 1)))))
```

The same function but using Temporal Recursion would be something like this:

```
;; A temporally recursive function with 0 delay
;; (callback (now) my-func (+ i 1)) ~= (my-func (+ i 1))
;; (now) here means immediately - straight away

(define my-func
  (lambda (i)
    (println 'i: i)
    (if (< i 5)
      (callback (now) my-func (+ i 1)))))
```

In the preceeding example (callback (now) my-func (+ i 1)) serves a similar function to (my-func (+ i 1)) - both are responsible for calling back into my-func immediately, passing an incremented value for i. However, the way in which these two recursive calls operate is substantially different. The temporal recursion, that is formed by the recursive call (callback (now) my-func (+ i 1)), is implemented as an event distinct from the current control-state. In other words, while the call (my-func (+ i 1)) maintains the control flow, and potentially (assuming no tail optimisation) the call stack, the (callback (now) my-func (+ i 1)) schedules my-func and then returns control flow to the real-time scheduler.

**My Question**
Given that I've the scheduler part up and running in C# and works well. I'm also able to schedule an F# function which will be called by the C# scheduler. But how to accomplish a scheduled function call where the function itself can be changed in real time using F# Interactive.

So what I would like to be able to do in F# interactive is something like:

```
let playMeAgain time<ms>
    instrument.Play "c4 e4 g4"
    callback (time<ms> playMeAgain)

playMeAgain 1000<ms>
```

And then, as soon as I change this function in F# Interactive to the following, the previous playMeAgain won't be called again but the new version of the function (the new binding to playMeAgain) will be called:

```
 let playMeAgain time<ms>
    instrument.Play "d4 f4 a4"
    callback (500<ms> playMeAgain)
```

Would this be possible at all under .NET? How to accomplish this "hot swappable" code technique under F#, given the fact that this is not recursion as F# defines recursion (and therefor needs the let rec playMeAgain syntax in order to compile properly).

For detailed info about Temporal Recursion see [this link](http://extempore.moso.com.au/temporal_recursion.html)

An excellent [example of why Temporal Recursion is a crucial technique in this domain](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tQIQwQnX3hA):

**CODE ADDED to facilitate discussion about Temporal recursion with parameters**
    module TemporalRecursion =
        open LcmMidi.MidiDotNet
        open LCM.Instrument
        open LCM.Sound.Sounds
        open LcmMidi.MidiDotNet

```
    let mutable private temporalRecursives : Map<string, obj -> obj> = Map.empty

    let private call name args =
        let fn = temporalRecursives |> Map.find name
        fn args

    let private againHandler (args:System.EventArgs) =
        let newArgs = args :?> LcmMidi.TemporalRecursionEventArgs 
        let name = newArgs.FunctionName
        call name ()
        |> ignore

    let defOstinato name (f: 'a -> 'b) =
        if (temporalRecursives.ContainsKey name) then
            temporalRecursives <- Map.remove name temporalRecursives
        temporalRecursives <- Map.add name (fun arg -> box <| f (unbox arg)) temporalRecursives
        fun (a: 'a) -> call name (box a) |> unbox<'b>

    let repOstinato (name:string) (time:float) =
        let message = new LcmMidi.TemporalRecursionMessage(name, float32 time)
        message.Again.Add againHandler
        LcmMidi.MidiDotNet.TimedScheduler.Instance.Schedule(message)
```

**Temporal Recursion with parameters**
What I would like to be able to do is something like:

```
let pp (notation:string) = 
    defOstinato "prepPiano" (fun (notation) -> 
        piano.Play notation
        let nextNotation = markovChainOfChords notation
        repOstinato ("prepPiano", 8. , nextNotation) 
    )

pp("c4e4g4)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the original answer I wrote, which provides a "general" solution, a la Lisp. But then I thought that maybe you don't need "general", maybe you just have one-two functions like this (i.e. "chords" and "percussion", that's it?). If that is the case, you may be satisfied with just keeping function references as mutable variables:

```
let mutable f : int -> int -> int = Unchecked.defaultof<_>
f <- fun a b -> a + b
f 5 6   // it = 11
f <- fun a b -> a - b
f 5 6   // it = -1
f <- fun a b -> if a % 2 = 0 then a + b else f b (a-1) // recursion
f 5 6   // it = 10

let mutable temporal : unit -> unit
temporal <- fun () -> doStuff; callback (time + 10) (fun () -> temporal())
```

This comes with a few inconveniences though:

1. You can't declare the variable, and initialize it, and have it recursive, all at the same time: mutable values can't be recursive. So you have to use the awkward trick with `Unchecked.defaultOt<_>` as initialization value, and then assign it separately.
2. Since you can't initialize the value inline, you have to specify its type explicitly.
3. The syntax of `let f <- fun x -> ...` is awkward. It kinda looks like `fun x` is in angle brackets.
4. When passing such function as argument to `callback`, you need to always wrap it in a lambda expression, like in my example: `(fun() -> temporal())`, otherwise `callback` will get a reference to the function as it was at the time of calling `callback`, not as it becomes at the scheduled time.

---

### Original answer

To achieve what Lisp achieves, you need to do what Lisp does - namely, define functions the way Lisp defines functions, not as static constructs outside of the program execution, but as a dictionary mapping names to code, i.e. `Map<string, obj -> obj>`.

To do this, obviously, you'll have to abandon the `let` construct and devise your own. Let's call it `defun`. It will take the name and the code as parameters, put them into the dictionary (the dictionary would have to be mutable, of course - and yes, that's how it actually works in Lisp), and return a "reference" of sorts - a wrapper that is itself a function with the same signature, but when called, it will first fetch the actual code from the dictionary and execute that.

Because your functions are probably all of different types, the whole thing will need to erase types (hence `obj -> obj`). That's a bit discomforting, but hey, it's no worse than Lisp! :-)

```
let mutable definitions : Map<string, obj -> obj> = Map.empty

let call name arg = 
    let fn = Map.find name definitions // NOTE: will throw when name is not defined
    fn arg 

let defun name (f: 'a -> 'b) = 
    definitions <- Map.add name (fun arg -> box <| f (unbox arg)) definitions
    fun (a: 'a) -> call name (box a) |> unbox<'b>
```

Usage:

```
let x = defun "x" (fun a b -> a + b)
x 5 6  // it = 11

defun "x" (fun a b -> a - b)
x 5 6  // it = -1
```

Note that you can technically break this by making a mistake:

```
defun "x" (fun a -> "Hello " + a)
x 5 6  // InvalidCastException
```

But hey, that's what Lisp would do as well!

But we're not out of the woods yet: still can't do recursion.

```
 let x = defun "x" (fun a b -> a + (x b a))  // `x` is not defined
```

Hm... You could technically just say `let rec x`, and it will work:

```
 let rec x = defun "x" (fun a b -> if a % 2 = 0 then a + b else x b (a-1))
 x 5 6   // it = 10
```

But this would generate you a compiler warning, because technically, depending on what the body of `x` is, the compiler can't guarantee that the whole definition won't cause infinite recursion. In this particular case it won't, because `x` is used inside a lambda expression that is not immediately invoked. But the compiler doesn't know that, hence the warning.

So you could technically just stop here. But this whole unsoundness irks me a bit, so I'll offer another way to do recursion: pass an extra parameter to the function, which would be a reference to itself. Then the function can call it or pass to `callback`:

```
let mutable definitions : Map<string, obj -> obj> = Map.empty

let call name arg = 
    let fn = Map.find name definitions
    fn arg // NOTE: will throw when name is not defined

let defun name (f: ('a -> 'b) -> 'a -> 'b) = 
    let self = fun (a: 'a) -> call name (box a) |> unbox<'b>
    definitions <- Map.add name (fun arg -> box <| f self (unbox arg)) definitions
    self

// Note: no `rec` keyword
let x = defun "x" (fun recur a b -> if a % 2 = 0 then a + b else recur b (a-1))
x 5 6  // it = 10

defun "x" (fun recur a b -> a - b)
x 5 6  // it = -1

defun "x" (fun recur a -> "Hello " + a)
x 5 6  // InvalidCastException
```

Comment: Thank,you so much. I was completely stuck but you put me into the right direction and it's working now :-) Concerning the recursivity, since it is the Scheduler that calls the function again I was able to keep the code quite clean. Thanks again so much for the help!!!!

Comment: Here a short video demonstrating the current implementation of Temporal Recursion. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bsi6b7SXAbA&lc (defun became defOstinato and planning the next callback is done with the repOstinato function). This is an implementation without parameters. Haven't been able to get that to work yet.  I guess the parameters have to be stored in the dictionary too and updated by repOstinato. Some help on this would be great.

Comment: I can't really say anything definitive, because I don't see your definitions of `defOstinato` and `repOstinato`, but right off the bat, I see that you're trying to recur your functions by name rather than by reference. This may not be the reason, but I can't say anything more without seeing your code.

Comment: Also, you mention parameters in your comment, but I don't see your functions having any parameters.

Comment: Fyoder, I should have added the code of the current implementation. Sorry for that. I've now added the source of the TemporalRecursion module at the end of the original post. Hope it facilitates the discussion. What you'll see is that a message is passed to the scheduler. The message contains both the name of the function to be called as well as when the function shall be called (measured in beats).

Comment: I've also added an example at the end of the post. It's an example with only one parameter but ideally the amount of parameters and type of parameters should be flexibly.

Comment: You're mixing defining functions and scheduler together. Don't. They don't need to depend on each other. Have the scheduler take a function `unit -> unit` and pass or a lambda expression with parameters baked in. `let f = defOstinato "f" (fun arg1 arg2 -> ...); repOstinato time (fun () -> f arg1 arg2)`.

Comment: I feel like you didn't _understand_ my solution, but trying to blindly copy parts of it.

Comment: Fyodor, I'm still studying to understand all the pieces of the puzzle together. It's not that easy to find the right information but I'm getting there. So, yes you are right but I'll get there! Thanks again so much for your help. Very much appreciated!!!!